# Transform form Input field into read-only after data is entered

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to update the below code with the following logic:
Once text is entered, make field read-only.
Basically, it's a signature field that we want to be locked as soon as someone enters a value.

```
<strong>Logistics Chief:</strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;"><input type="text" style="width: 200px; height: 22px;" value="" fieldname="Field_31"><br>
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, but what have you tried?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: "as soon as someone enters a value" - after adding the first character? After leaving the form? After submitting the form?

Comment: After clicking out of the box.   So types in name, clicks out and box is now read only

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve that? Pure HTML won't do that, you need some kind of JS for this

Comment: I just tried playing with the "readonly" command (I'm very much a newbie to HTML so excuse my ignorance)  I guess i was playing around to see if there were any conditional functions like in excel, whee i could get the form element to behave in a way that is desirable for a signature box, etc.   I thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with some vanilla JavaScript. Here are 2 functions written to lock and unlock the input field. Using the input's HTML attribute `onfocusout=""` we access the event for un-focusing the field, aka leaving the edit mode of the field. I then added a button to unlock it again, as the user will be mighty irritated if he/she managed to put a type-o in there and no alternative is available for fixing it.

The HTML:

```
<td>
    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;">
        <input id="signature_input" onfocusout="lock_signature_field()" type="text" style="width: 200px; height: 22px;" fieldname="Field_31">
        <br><br>
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="unlock_signature_field()">Edit Signature</button>
</td>
```

Here's that same HTML again with less clutter, more copy-paste:able:

```
<td>
    <span>
        <input id="signature_input" onfocusout="lock_signature_field()" type="text"fieldname="name">
        <br><br>
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="unlock_signature_field()">Edit Signature</button>
</td>
```

**The JS** (put right before the  in the bottom of the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // set reference to the dom input field
    const signatureField = document.getElementById("signature_input");

    function lock_signature_field() {
        signatureField.setAttribute('readonly', true);
        console.log('Element was locked.'); // you can remove this debug-line if you want.
    }

    function unlock_signature_field() {
        signatureField.removeAttribute("readonly"); // we have to remove the attribute alltogether, cause setting it to false, will do nothing in most browsers.
        console.log('Element was unlocked.'); // you can remove this debug-line if you want.
    }

</script>
```

Here it is in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andioak/r0by7qdu/1/)!

Comment: No worries. This example is for every time the user steps out of the field with the mouse or leaves with a tab on the keyboard. It could be set up to have a timer to lock only after the user has been out of the field for a certain number of seconds. But for this one field, it's probably ok. Good luck.

Comment: @vmackey Consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark if it is the best answer :D